# Change affinity of process with windows script

Tags: windows, batch-file, affinity

In Windows, with

```
 START /node 1 /affinity ff cmd /C "app.exe"
```

I can set the affinity of app.exe (number of cores used by app.exe).

With a windows script, How I can change the affinity of a running process ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

PowerShell can do this task for you.

###### Get Affinity

```
$Process = Get-Process app
$Process | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity
```

###### Set Affinity

```
$Process = Get-Process app
$Process.ProcessorAffinity = 255
```

##### Example <sub><sup>( 8 Core Processor )</sup></sub>

| Core # | Value | BitMask |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Core 1 | 1 | 0x00000001 |
| Core 2 | 2 | 0x00000010 |
| Core 3 | 4 | 0x00000100 |
| Core 4 | 8 | 0x00001000 |
| Core 5 | 16 | 0x00010000 |
| Core 6 | 32 | 0x00100000 |
| Core 7 | 64 | 0x01000000 |
| Core 8 | 128 | 0x10000000 |

Just add the decimal values together for which core you want to use.

- **All 8 Cores** = *Value:* **255** = *BitMask:* **0x11111111**

##### Using with cmd.exe

You can use the PowerShell code from within the cmd shell by calling the PowerShell process with the code as an argument. Separate commands with a semi-colon.

```
> powershell.exe "Get-Process notepad++ | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity"

                                                         ProcessorAffinity
                                                         -----------------
                                                                       255


> powershell.exe "$p = Get-Process notepad++; $p.ProcessorAffinity = 13"

> powershell.exe "Get-Process notepad++ | Select-Object ProcessorAffinity"

                                                         ProcessorAffinity
                                                         -----------------
                                                                        13
```

## Source

Here is a nicely detailed post on how to change a process's affinity:

***Setting Processor Affinity** @ EnergizedTech*
[archive.today](https://archive.today/UvaxX) / [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/2015/http://www.energizedtech.com/2010/07/powershell-setting-processor-a.html)
<sup><sub>*(the broken images weren't important)*</sub></sup>

Comment: the first command works fine.   but for the 2nd I get this message:   "The property 'ProcessorAffinity' cannot be found on this object. Verify that 
the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:32
+ $Process = Get-Process chrome; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=1
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
 
"

Comment: How can this be used if there are multiple processes with the same name (e.g., java)?  Does it set the affinity of all the java processes, or pick one at random (or lowest pid, etc.)

Comment: @DanielWiddis  Using `Get-Process java | ...` will change the affinity for all of the java processes.  If you just want a specific instance of java, you will have to know and use the process ID.  e.g. `Get-Process -ID 8500`  Otherwise, you will have to implement your own filtering.

Comment: Hust a heads-up to anyone reading this via Google that if you don't want to use PowerShell, or need to invoke from a command prompt using the `cmd /start "" /Affinity value` method, core affinity is actually *hexadecimal*. e.g., to launch a process using cores 13-16 on a 16-core CPU, the decimal value is `61440` and the hex is `0xF000`. Using `61440` will launch a process using cores 6,10 and 12 :-) https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-hex.html is useful for quick conversion.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer works, but only for the first process in the list. The solution to that in the comments does not work for me.

To change affinity of all processes with the same name use this:

```
Powershell "ForEach($PROCESS in GET-PROCESS processname) { $PROCESS.ProcessorAffinity=255}"
```

Where `255` is the mask as given in the accepted answer.

Comment: Need period to be right after the  $PROCESS like $PROCESS.ProcessorAffinity=255

Comment: true, I changed it.

Comment: This is super verbose; just use `Get-Process $processName | % { $_.ProcessorAffinity = $value; };`

Comment: Still too verbose: use `Get-Process $pn| %{ $_.ProcessorAffinity = $v}` /s

Comment: Still too verbose — use `(ps $p).ProcessorAffinity=$v` /s

Comment: @StarsonHochschild I get two errors with your command. 1. `Unexpected token 's'`, 2. `The property 'ProcessorAffinity' cannot be found on this object.`. How is your command supposed to be used?

Comment: Guys, if you are confused like me, this is what I ended up with `ps $p | %{ $_.ProcessorAffinity = $v }` e.g. `ps chrome | %{ $_.ProcessorAffinity = 63 }`

Comment: @Qwerty Look carefully, the /s is not part of the command.  It was a "sarcasm" indicator, just like the comment from Dimesio ;)

Comment: @StarsonHochschild One never knows on the internet. I can't know if it's bad formatting, mistake, copypasta or intentional without knowing the context. Anyway, if I remove `/s`, which I did, I get the error number 2. Is it failing because the object is an array?

Comment: @Qwerty Ah, yes, that form is incompatible if `ps` returns multiple processes.  It's better to use your solution which handles both cases.  No big deal because like I said I meant that comment more as a continuation of the "too verbose" rather than a real solution

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for answers to this and not finding any, the solution I found was to use an app called [WinAFC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/affinitychanger/) (or AffinityChanger). This is a partial GUI, partial command line app that allows you to specify profiles for certain executables, and will poll the process list for them. If it finds matching processes, it will change the affinity of those processes according to the settings in the loaded profile.

There is some documentation here: http://affinitychanger.sourceforge.net/

For my purposes, I created a profile that looked like this:

```
TestMode = 0
TimeInterval = 1
*\convert.exe := PAIR0+PAIR1
```

This profile sets any convert.exe process to use the first two CPU core pairs (CPU0, CPU1, CPU2, and CPU3), polling every second. `TestMode` is a toggle that allows you to see if your profile is working without actually setting affinities.

Hope someone finds this useful!

Comment: I'm find this program a bit patchy.  I know it's old, so wondered if you still use it successfully?  It looks great, but it picks up some programs and not others.

Comment: It's been SO long since I did this. I know it worked for me at the time. I haven't needed to use the program since then; it was a short-term thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you really like enums, you can do it this way.  ProcessorAffinity is an IntPtr, so it takes a little extra type casting.

```
[flags()] Enum Cores {
  Core1 = 0x0001
  Core2 = 0x0002
  Core3 = 0x0004
  Core4 = 0x0008
  Core5 = 0x0010
  Core6 = 0x0020
  Core7 = 0x0040
  Core8 = 0x0080
}

$a = get-process notepad

[cores][int]$a.Processoraffinity
Core1, Core2, Core3, Core4

$a.ProcessorAffinity = [int][cores]'core1,core2,core3,core4'
```