# Batch/CMD - Change Core affinity of a running process

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to change the core affinity of a already running process on the commandline?

Example:

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
:TASKLIST
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq iexplore.exe" | find /i "iexplore.exe"      

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO LOOP2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LOOP1 

:LOOP1 
  Change Core affinity to all cores
goto EXIT     

:LOOP1 
  timeout 5 >nul
goto TASKLIST

:EXIT
```

I know how to start a programm with the core affinity set, but I would like to know how I could do that with a running process?

Comment: There is a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187241/change-affinity-of-process-with-windows-script), do you require to do that without PowerShell ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the infos. It would be perfect if we could do it without PowerShell.

Comment: Call **start /?**. Read about parameter **/AFFINITY**.